# How to build create-react-app with different settings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I built the project with create-react-app following most of their structure recommendations. It's more than year of active development. Now the client wants to be able to build a project with different logos, colors and icons for many subcontractors. I don't have one general file of styles. All styles are divided into components and imported to js files. I guess that i future it also will be difference between logic.

For now I'm looking for best solutions/practices to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this NPM to create react app, you can build an app easily

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-redux-app-structure

, or if you want to build the project then you should use web pack :), Its always work for me.